# .net core 2 weird bug when trying to pass parameter to mysql command

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, asp.net-core-2.0

```
_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($@"UPDATE table SET column = 
CONCAT(column,'?{string}') WHERE id = {id}");
```

string is a string variable that contains a value to be appended in the database
but somehow the string that is appended in the database is ?@p0 instead of ?value 
I'm using pomelo mysql.

Comment: You're opening yourself up to SQL injection here, much safer to use parameters for example: `_context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT(column,'{0}') WHERE id = {1}", "stringParameter", intParameter);`

Comment: @DavidG I thought the method I use here prevents SQL injection

Comment: The moment you start concatenating strings to make SQL is when you are vulnerable to SQL injection, that's why we always use parameters.

Comment: @DavidG also I tried that way and it still stores ?@p0

Comment: And you used the code exactly as I posted it?

Comment: @DavidG yep, if I just do with by concatenating strings it works fine, but I know thats vulnerable to sql injection thats why I wanted to do it the by passing parameters but somehow this bug occurs

Answer (score 0):

take a look on "Dapper" library to interact with your DB.
And then for the code you can do this:

```
using Dapper;

string sql = "UPDATE table SET column = CONCAT(column, @s) WHERE id = @id";
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(yourConnectionString))
{
        try
        {
            connection.Execute(sql, new { @id = yourid, s = string });
        }
        catch (SqlException e)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(e);
        }
}
```